# Loading Electron window after getting all data from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I am using Electron. I am loading one HTML page in BrowserWindow. Window loads first its half part stays blank and after getting data from JavaScript, it displays that data.

I have tried using the `ready-to-show`, `dom-ready`, `did-finish-load` events, but I have the same issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="DivHeader">
   <h1 class="heading" style="font-family: cursive;">Log Viewer</h1>
   <p><img class="f5logo" src="../images/index.png" </p>
</div>

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 2000px;width:100%;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "but I have the same issue" - and what exactly is the issue? The browser window doesn't load the page? Where is the code that loads the page into the browser window? Where is the code showing your attempts (e.g. ready-to-show, dom-ready, etc.)?

Comment: The issue is ,Window loads half part first and other part remains blank as it waits to receive data from javascript code. And after receiving data it displays that . 
I want to display window getting all data so that it will not show half part first and remaining after receiving data.

Please find below electron code,

mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
   mainWindow.show()
 })

Comment: Hide the first part until the second part shows?